# Is there some deep difference in Python between methods that alter the object and ones that do not?

Tags: python, methods

For instance, in the case of

```
>>> f.read()
'This statement is false.\n'
>>> f
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='test.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'> 
>>> f.seek(0) 
>>> f.read()
'This statement is false.\n'
```

`f` is still a file object with the same contents. Whereas with

```
>>> lst = []
>>> lst.append(2)
>>> lst
[2]
```

the list `lst` is altered.

Is this difference an instance of a general theme or trend? Is there a special set of methods that alter the object? (In my example, would `f` be considered altered by `f.seek(0)`?)

Comment: Just because the underlying *file* isn't modified doesn't mean the `TextIOWrapper` instance isn't. The file position is updated by both `read` and `seek`.

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not the object is altered by a method does not make the method any different. So to answer your question: no.

However, of course, some methods are designed with the purpose of altering the object, and some are designed not to alter the object.

(Also, there are of course `classmethod`s and `staticmethod`s, which cannot alter the instance - otherwise they wouldn't be class or static methods!)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you have in mind, but in general, no, there is no fundamental distinction between methods that alter their object and those that do not. Python has nothing akin to the `const` keyword of C or C++.

In fact, sometimes it is intentionally not revealed whether a method alters the object it acts on. This is to allow for different implementations under the hood, some of which will alter the object's state and some of which won't. This does have implications when writing parallel code (e.g. using `multiprocessing`): objects might not be safe to use concurrently from multiple threads, and they might not tell you explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the objective for this question. All languages have methods that need modify the object and methods that not modify the object. If you want append a element to a array is impossible that you don't modify the object.
The answer is that depends that you want to do, the method need alter or not the object.

Comment: Objective for the question is just to understand the structure of Python a bit better.

Comment: How i said, all depends of the objective that the method has. For example you can't append a element to a array and not alter the object, but if the objective is simply show some information, that method not alter the object.